# TypeError: can't access property "nodeValue", node is null

Tags: vuejs3, vite

In vue3 component I have this code:

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {

      vendedores: [{
id: 1,
nombre: "Name test1"
}],
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Having this template, there everything works fine:

```
<div v-for="vendedor in vendedores"
     :key="vendedor.id">
</div>
```

But in this one is displaying an error everytime vite compiles the assets:

```
<div v-for="vendedor in vendedores"
     :key="vendedor.id">
  <button
      :class="(vendedor.seleccionado)? 'bg-zinc-800 border-amber-300' : 'bg-transparent'"
      class="border-zinc-400 rounded-full py-3 text-left hover:border-violet-200"
  >
    <span> Test</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

The error displayed in the console is the following:

```
TypeError: can't access property "nodeValue", node is null
    setText runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:30
    processText runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5109
    patch runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5064
    patchKeyedChildren runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5849
    patchChildren runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5792
    patchElement runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5305
    processElement runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5165
    patch runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5082
    ...
```

I have updated @vite to last version (^3.2.0) and vue3 (3.2.41). Other components working fine in other projects with the same version.

Comment: `v-for` is not allowed on root nodes. Try to wrap your `div` into another one.

Comment: Your snippet of code works perfectly on my side, when wrapped into another div.

Comment: Wrapping into another div did not fix it. I am considering reinstalling the project.

Comment: May be an approach yeah. The error is not coming from the given snippet at least. Do you have any console/ESlint errors?